# jQuery hasClass conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

The conditional should be met only if the clicked element has no class `agallery` or `aslide`. This is not working for me.

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('agallery') || !$(this).hasClass('aslide')){
  //do certain things
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more of your Jquery code and/or the HTML you are working with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(!($(this).hasClass('agallery') || $(this).hasClass('aslide'))){
```

Basically, you should read this as "not (either A or B)", while Clive's equivalent is "(not A) and (not B)".

Your condition "(not A) or (not B)" is true if it doesn't have one.  So it will only be false if it has both classes.

Comment: Or, applying De Morgan's... Clive's answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `&&` instead:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('agallery') && !$(this).hasClass('aslide')){
  //do certain things
}
```

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Or, applying De Morgan's... Matthew Flaschen's answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the non jQuery way using a regex on the class name directly:

```
if (!this.className.match(/\bagallery\b|\baslide\b/)) {
    // do certain things
}
```